# Не работает node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Не могу понять правильно ли установился Node Js на Windows.
Вызываю просмотр версии node и npm в терминале. Результат только для npm.

```
C:\Users\Andrey>npm -v
8.19.2

C:\Users\Andrey>node --version
Node Commands

Syntax:
    node {operator} [options] [arguments]

Parameters:
        /? or /help   - Display this help message.
        list          - List nodes or node history or the cluster
        listcores     - List cores on the cluster
        view          - View properties of a node
        online        - Set nodes or node to online state
        offline       - Set one or more nodes to the offline state

For more information about HPC command-line tools,
see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=120724.
```

Установленная версия 18.12.0

Не работает даже инициализация пакета и просмотр команд NodeJS

```
PS G:\Courses_projects\CoursesJS\npm> node list
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:5800
PS G:\Courses_projects\CoursesJS\npm> npm i
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path G:\Courses_projects\CoursesJS\npm/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Courses_projects\CoursesJS\npm\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-26T15_05_10_752Z-debug-0.log
PS G:\Courses_projects\CoursesJS\npm>
```

Comment: вы смотрите системную команду `node`, а не node.js. Введите `node.exe -v`

Comment: `node -v` тоже работает )

Comment: С `node -v` аналогично

Comment: npm i не выполняется потому что в той папке где вы выполняете - нет файла package.json

Comment: npm i с package.json работает, но запуск приложения нет. Не работает даже обычный вызов скрипта через node